# Accessing values from another array of objects while doing $lookup in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

There are two collections, user and project.

User Object:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId(SOME_ID),
    name: "Full Name",
    projects: [projectIdA, projectIdB] 
    lastAccessed: [
        {
            id: projectIdA,
            ts: date1
        }, 
        {
            id: projectIdB, 
            ts: date2
        }
    ]
}
```

Project Object:

```
{
    _id: projectIdA, 
    name: "Project 1",
    desc: "Some Desc"

}
```

Now, when I want to fetch the user details, I want project details for each project id stored in projects array of user collection along with the last accessed.

Like this response -

```
{
    _id: ObjectId(SOME_ID),
    name: "Full Name",
    projects: [
        {
            id: projectIdA,
            name: "Project 1",
            desc: "Some Desc",
            ts: date1
        }, 
        {
            id: projectIdB,
            name: "Project 2",
            desc: "Some Desc",
            ts: date1
        }, 
    ]
}
```

The project details from project collection can be added using the `$lookup` in MongoDB. But how to access the `lastAccessed` field for each project?

Answer (score 0):

- `$lookup` with `project` collection
- `$map` to iterate loop of `lastAccessed` array
- `$filter` to iterate loop of `projects` array and filter matching project
- `$arrayElemAt` to get first element from above filtered project
- `$mergeObejcts` to merge current object field with result fields

```
db.user.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "project",
      localField: "projects",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "projects"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      name: 1,
      projects: {
        $map: {
          input: "$lastAccessed",
          as: "l",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$l",
              {
                $arrayElemAt: [
                  {
                    $filter: {
                      input: "$projects",
                      cond: { $eq: ["$$this._id", "$$l.id"] }
                    }
                  },
                  0
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tqKF06-Vyiv)

Comment: It works fine if element is present in lastAccessed array. But in case the element is not present there, is there any option to show null?

Comment: no it is hard to show all fields with null, I would suggest you can do it in front end side after query.

Comment: If an element is present in projects array but not in lastAccessed, then null should be displayed. But it is not happening. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: It worked when I replaced "$lastAccessed" with "$projects" in $map and tried to merge with lastAccessed